# Duplicate domain name in DNS query

Tags: rhel, dns

I found out strange duplicate domain name in the DNS queries during `tcpdump` capturing on my RedHat server. It did not do any impact on my DNS names resolving.

But it's not clear why my server sends such request in DNS query  ==> `my.domainspec.com.domainspec.com.domainspec.com`. In general it should be
just `my.domainspec.com`

info from tcpdump:

```
12:17:28.431208 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57779, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 97)
my.domainspec.com.33953 > ns1.entry.com.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xcb8a -> 0x6e04!] 63367+ A? my.domainspec.com.domainspec.com.domainspec.com. (69)`
`12:17:28.431718 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61601, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 148)
    ns1.entry.com.domain > my.domainspec.com.33953: [udp sum ok] 63367 NXDomain* q: A? my.domainspec.com.domainspec.com.domainspec.com. 0/1/0 ns: domainspec.com. SOA ns1.entry.com. postmaster.domainspec.com. 2018012732 600 300 2592000 900 (120)
```

info from `nsswitch.conf`:

```
 grep "hosts" /etc/nsswitch.conf
 #hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
 hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

info from `/etc/hosts`:

```
193.48.203.195  my.domainspec.com
```

info from `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
 # Generated by NetworkManager
 search domainspec.com
 nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

**Please note.** I've used fake domain names and IPs for the example.

Could someone explain what the reason for the duplicate domain name in DNS query is? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Good that you tell us it is fake, because the `tcpdump` and `resolv.conf`, and even `nameserver`do not match.

Comment: Provide the true names involved without useless obfuscation, even more when it is confusing and not using the appropriate values (as detailed in RFC2606, use `example.com`, or `.example` TLD next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing pretty much normal, known and documented behaviour.

What it happens is when the resolver is not able to resolve a DNS name, it will try to resolve it appending all the domains in your `search` directive to the original query on turns (if it does not got a match in middle-process).

The process is a bit convoluted in itself, and several search domains can be combined due to the recursive nature of the process.

The way to somewhat minimize/avoid the domain expansion, when resolving DNS names, is in the `search` directive (or wherever you configure your search domains), or even at applicational level, terminating the DNS/domain names with a ".".

As in:

```
search domainspec.com. domain.com. example.com.
```

In addition, as an example, when doing a ping,  domain search expansion can also be avoided in a case-by-case basis:

```
ping www.example.com.
```

or

```
ping www.cnn.com.
```

From [man resolv.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)

> search    Search list for host-name lookup.
>
> ```
>           The search list is normally determined from the local domain
>           name; by default, it contains only the local domain name.
>           This may be changed by listing the desired domain search path
>           following the search keyword with spaces or tabs separating
>           the names.  Resolver queries having fewer than ndots dots
>           (default is 1) in them will be attempted using each component
>           of the search path in turn until a match is found.  For
>           environments with multiple subdomains please read options
>           ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and
>           unnecessary traffic for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this
>           process may be slow and will generate a lot of network traffic
>           if the servers for the listed domains are not local, and that
>           queries will time out if no server is available for one of the
>           domains.
>
>           The search list is currently limited to six domains with a
>           total of 256 characters.
> ```